# Youtube api player for android copyright issue

Tags: youtube-api

The new android youtube api allows developer to embed and play videos in the third party app. I made android app that shows list of youtube videos and show video in the app (not using youtube official app).

I want to know if there will be any copyright issues for the same.

Do I need any permissions or something?

Posting this question here because youtube has mentioned to use stack-overflow with tag "youtube-api" as the official support group. See this link
https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow_14.html

Comment: If you're using the official YouTube API, there should not be any concern about copyright permissions. If rights holders put restrictions on their videos or ask for them to be removed, then they will no longer be accessible via the API and so you won't have to worry about them showing up in your app.

Comment: Thanks @jlmcdonald Same hold true for website also right?
Also please put this as answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @jlmcdonald thanks for sharing information... I have a question assume, I create a Playlist using my own Gmail and then I've copied few YouTube Video links from different - different channels... after that I am parsing same Playlist using API in my Android App... IS IT LEGAL OR NOT ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the official API to show videos, either on Android or for a Web App, then this should not be a concern as the API will only give you videos that haven't been restricted by the content owners (or if there is a concern over content, the videos will be removed, and hence your apps will no longer be displaying them).

When it comes to uploading, if you utilize oAuth authentication with v3 of the API then users who upload videos will be responsible for whatever is uploaded to their YouTube account through your app. That is, you won't have to worry about doing copyright checks yourself, as that will happen once the video ends up on the YouTube servers (this is the best reason to utilize this authentication method; if an app instead were to forego oAuth authentication and have uploads go into the app owner's account, then the app owner could be liable for copyright infringing videos sent through the app).

Note that this isn't legal advice or an official YouTube perspective; just my interpretation of reading the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) (which you should read as well).