# Application suspended from Play console with reason Copyrighted contents while using YouTubePlayer Android SDK

Tags: android, youtube-api

My app was published on Google Play Console. But after 6 days, my app has been suspended from Google Play Console with the reason of copyrighted contents. I am using 'YouTube Android Player SDK' to play YouTube videos.

Please let me know what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suspension rollback by **Google** after writing proper mail, explaining that we have not used any copyrighted content in our App and followed all guideline by **Google** and **YouTube**

Answer (score 0):

You may check the [YouTube API Services Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service) page. Also, base from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583312/youtube-api-player-for-android-copyright-issue), *if you are using the official API to show videos, either on Android or for a Web App, then this should not be a concern as the API will only give you videos that haven't been restricted by the content owners (or if there is a concern over content, the videos will be removed, and hence your apps will no longer be displaying them).*

Hope this helps!